# Laravel 5.2 How to get all user which contains permission Many to Many

Tags: laravel

I have table with many to many relationship.

User many to many Permission

I already define many to many relationship on both model, and create the pivot table also.

What I want is get all user which contain permission name

What I have done so far is

```
User::all()->permissions->contains('name', 'access.backend.admin')->get();
```

But it give me

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$permissions on line 1
```

What wrong with my code?

Comment: try this User::all()->permissions()->contains('name', 'access.backend.admin')->get(); will work

Comment: @umefarooq User::all() returns a collection not model object, so I don't think `->permissions()` function will work on collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User::All()` returns a collection not model object. You have iterate over the collection to get the model object and use `->permissions()`.

For exapmle:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->permissions->contains('name', 'access.backend.admin'); // returns boolean 
}
```

Or you can get a single model from DB as:

```
$user = User::first();
$user->permissions->contains('name', 'access.backend.admin'); // returns boolean
```

**Update 1**

To get users which contain desired permission use [filter()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-filter) method as:

```
$filtered_users = $users->filter(function ($user) {
    if ($user->permissions->contains('name', 'access.backend.admin')) {
        return $user;
    }
});
```

**Update 2**

You can also write a query which returns the desired result as:

```
$filtered_users = User::whereHas('permissions', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'access.backend.admin');
})->get()
```

Comment: What about if I need to pass the user which contain permission to the view? how to define new variable which contain users which contain desired permission?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case of questions and tags, they have many to many relationship.
So when i have to fetch all question with a particular tag then i do this

```
$tag = Tag::where('name','laravel')->get()->first();
```

I first retrieved the Tag model with name laravel.
and then retrieved all questions having tag laravel.

```
$questions = $tag->questions;
```

Similarly you can do this

```
$permission = Permission::where('name','access.backend.admin')->get()->first();
$users = $permission->users;
```

Comment: This approach is not optimized as it executes two queries whereas we can get the desired result in a single query by using [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) function.